# change src image on hover using css

Tags: html, css

2 image appear in same time, up and down.
I want hover image display none.

Hover image is appear below primary image.
Primary image is hide when hover.

Seems like dont work. and really need help on this.

```css
.card-img-top {
    border-radius: 0;
 height: 250px;
 width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(0%, 0%);
 object-fit: cover;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card a img {
  display: block;
}
.card a:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4"> 
    <a href="#">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/True Blue Asia.jpg"/>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/Asia Bagus.jpg"/>
        <div class="card-img-overlay d-table-cell align-middle">
            <p>true blue asia</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card-date">Oct 2019</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                    <div class="card-title">Roots, Heritage, Authenticity</div>
                    <div class="card-content">Asia’s myriad cultures manifest in practices derived from traditional value systems.</div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>            
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="/image_displayed_as_default" class="hover-hidden"/>
    <img src="/image_displayed_when_hover" class="hover-only"/>
</div>
```

```
.card img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
}
.card:hover img.hover-hidden,
.card:not(:hover) img.hover-only {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: i change opacity to display none.. its working.. thanks sir

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for this

> Pure CSS solution

```css
#aks {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    background:url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
    padding:50px;
}

#aks:hover {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
```

```html
<img id="aks" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff"/>
```

**Your code solution**

> Issue i you are not hide second image initially

```css
.card-img-top {
    border-radius: 0;
 height: 250px;
 width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(0%, 0%);
 object-fit: cover;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card a img {
  display: block;
}
.card a:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.card a .card-img-below{
  display: none;
}
.card a:hover .card-img-below {
  display: block;
}
a{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
 <a href="#">
  <img class="card-img-above" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_15-128.png"/>
  <img class="card-img-below" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_12-128.png"/>
  <div class="card-img-overlay d-table-cell align-middle">
   <p>true blue asia</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
     <div class="card-date">Oct 2019</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
     <div class="card-title">Roots, Heritage, Authenticity</div>
     <div class="card-content">Asia’s myriad cultures manifest in practices derived from traditional value systems.</div>
    </div>
   </div>    
  </div>            
 </a>
</div>
```

Change the image `url`

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. but im looking for another option using src hover image without js

Comment: Dear, The first one is pure `css` Solution second one is using `JS`

Comment: im using this option https://jsfiddle.net/m4v1onyL/
but not sure why hover image is appear

Comment: Its simple First he hide the second image and then on hover he display over that and hide first one. as second image is below first in html so it come over top

Comment: I follow exactly but weirdly not working. Hover image appear before hover

Comment: @Tat I updated your code. My last solution is using your code just change the `url`